# Adding new element(s) to Spinner Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, android-arrayadapter, http-get

I'm new to `Kotlin` language and I'm going to load `Spinner` data from the website. For this reason, I used [Fuel Library](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel) as my `httpGet`,`httpPost` and ... helper library and simply the `Spinner` Control for showing that data to the user. Below is my tried code:

```
var listOfLesson:List<String> = listOf()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.ostad_page)

    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfLesson)
    "home/GetAllLessons".httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
        when (result) {
            is Result.Success -> {
                val lessonsArray: List<tblLesson> =
                        Gson().fromJson(result.value, Array<tblLesson>::class.java).toList()
                var index:Int = 0
                for (lesson: tblLesson in lessonsArray) {
                    listOfLesson.plusElement(lesson.Title)
                }
                showSuccess("لیست دروس بارگذاری شد")
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    lessons.setAdapter(adapter)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

As I traced `Result.Success` part, everything was ok and data was loaded successfully from URL into `listOfLesson` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` executed without any error but the result was nothing and no entry added to `Spinner`.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `plusElement` on a `List` does not add an element to the existing list (remember, `List` in Kotlin is immutable). Rather, it creates a new list with the new item added. The original list (the one the adapter uses) remains unchanged. Furthermore, rather than adding to the list, what you should do is add the new items to the adapter directly. That way the adapter will update itself without you having to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ArrayList<String>())
"home/GetAllLessons".httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
    when (result) {
        is Result.Success -> {
            Gson().fromJson(result.value, Array<tblLesson>::class.java)
                .map { it.Title }
                .let { adapter.addAll(it) }
            showSuccess("لیست دروس بارگذاری شد")
        }
    }
}
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
lessons.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but following error occurred: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation is not supported for read-only collection`

Comment: @YasharAliabasi I've changed the first line. You can remove `listOfLesson`, you don't need it anymore.